# Command line search through specific folders for specific files

Tags: windows, command-line

Erroneously put this to StackOverflow first:

Simple search for files, but it's got me stumped. Using the command line, I can search for directories named jam with:

```
dir /AD jam /S
```

And I can look for files named sandwiches with

```
dir /S *sandwiches* /B
```

Is there a quick way I can combine the two commands and look for files named sandwiches, but only in folders called jam? That is, without piping all the files to text and sifting through them both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, by regular commands provided by the windows installation, this is not possible (afak).

The command `dir` is not capable to process "regular expressions" (in contrast to `findstr`). So you are urged to feed the output of `dir` to `findstr`, to obtain your selection.

Unless there is an advanced third-party `dir`-command out there, that can process something similar to "regular expressions", this is probably the simplest variant to display your files of interest:

```
dir /B /S /A-D *sandwiches* | findstr -I ".*jam.*[\\]"
```

This lists all files with `sandwiches` in the filename and throws away any lines, that do not contain `jam` as part of a directory name, before the list is going to be displayed.

Unfortunately in your question you excluded the possibility of a pipe in the desired command, so this is probably the nearest/shortest possibility to get the selection (realized by commands provided with Windows), but its not a solution in the frame of your conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is about the "normal" command line/prompt. However, you can try Powershell to get the result you are looking for:

```ps
Get-ChildItem -Directory "jam" | ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem -Path $_ | Where-Object { $_.Name -like "*sandwiches*"} | Select-Object Name }
```

You can shorten the above cmdlets to:

```ps
gci -Directory "jam" | foreach { gci -Path $_ | ? { $_.Name -like "*sandwiches*"} | select Name }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could download [grep](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) for Windows and use:

```
dir /s /b | grep -E "jam\\[^\\]*sandwiches[^\\]*"
```

Which matches anything ending with `jam\`, then any characters other than `\` followed by `sandwiches` and again anything except `\`

And here's a PowerShell solution with less piping than in the other answer:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Include "jam" | % { Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Filter "*sandwiches*" -Name }
```

Or if you want full path, which is better for recursive operation to know where the files are:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory -Include "jam" | % { Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Filter "*sandwiches*" | Select FullName }
```

You could also pipe the paths to `Resolve-Path -Relative` for relative ones.